# I want to use one switch case instead of two switch cases

Tags: c

```
int SumOfCards(char str[], int n)
{
   if(n==0)
   return -1;
   int sum1,sum2;
   char temp[2];
   if(str[1]==' ')
   temp[0]= str[2];
   else if(str[2]==' ')
   temp[0] = str[3];

switch(str[0])
{
    case '2' : sum1 = 2;
    break;
    case '3' : sum1 = 3;
    break;
    case '4' : sum1 = 4;
    break;
    case '5' : sum1 = 5;
    break;
    case '6' : sum1 = 6;
    break;
    case '7' : sum1 = 7;
    break;
    case '8' : sum1 = 8;
    break;
    case '9' : sum1 = 9;
    break;
    case '1' : sum1 = 10;
    break;
    case 'K' : sum1 = 10;
    break;
    case 'J' : sum1 = 10;
    break;
    case 'Q' : sum1 = 10;
    break;
    case 'A' : sum1 = 11;
    break;
    default : sum1 = 0;
    break;

}
 switch(temp[0])
{

    case '2' : sum2 = 2;
    break;
    case '3' : sum2 = 3;
    break;
    case '4' : sum2 = 4;
    break;
    case '5' : sum2 = 5;
    break;
    case '6' : sum2 = 6;
    break;
    case '7' : sum2 = 7;
    break;
    case '8' : sum2 = 8;
    break;
    case '9' : sum2 = 9;
    break;
    case '1' : sum2 = 10;
    break;
    case 'K' : sum2 = 10;
    break;
    case 'J' : sum2 = 10;
    break;
    case 'Q' : sum2 = 10;
    break;
    case 'A' : sum2 = 11;
    break;
    default : sum2 = 0;
    break;

}
   if(str[0]== 'A' && temp[0]== 'A')
   {sum1 = 1;
   sum2 = 1;
   }
   int sum = sum1 + sum2;
   return sum;

}
```

This is a program for sum of two cards value from deck of card. Cards consist value from 2,3,...10 and J, A, Q and K. str[0] consist the value of first card and temp[0] consist the value of second card I want to use one switch case instead of two switch case because cases for str[0] and temp[0] are same. So, can i use only one switch case instead of two switch case. How, can i do it?

Comment: Write a function.

Comment: Consider writing a function to convert a `char cardName` into its value. Hint: for cards `'2'` to `'9'` the value of the card is `cardName - '2' + 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it simply by putting the logic in a **function** and calling with once with `temp[0]` and once again with `str[0]`. That is what functions are for. Instead of repeating the logic put it in a function and call it multiple times.

Also instead of `switch` cases `if` statement will serve a better purpose here. Something like:-

```
func(str[0],&sum2);
...
func(temp[0],&someintvar);
```

And then

```
void func(char c, int *a){
   if( c>='2' && c<='9')
      *a = c-'0';
   else if( c=='1' || c=='J' || c=='K' || c=='A' || c=='Q')
      *a = 10;
   else
      *a = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can reduce the statement: `else if( c=='1' || c=='J' || c=='K' || c=='A' || c=='Q')`  to  `else if(strchr("1JKAQ", c)) {...}`

Comment: @machine_1.: Yes I thought of that. But I am not sure how much OP will appreciate it. (I guess OP is a beginner) but it's a *good* way. Thanks for commenting here.